# Java BufferedReader Switch case same line stored in array

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement, bufferedreader

I'm trying to loop through a file to read "accounts" from a file into an arraylist called `accounts`. This is the file:

```
c 1111 1234 703.92
x 2222 1234 100.00
s 3333 1234 200.08
```

I know it's looping to the next line since I print the id and it goes from 1111 to 2222 to 3333, but at the bottom when I print the account's tostring, they're all the same one (the "s" line in the file). Why is this happening?

Bank.main:

```
private static ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //if incorrect # or bankfile can't be opened, print to system error
    //Usage: java Bank bankFile [batchFile]

    if(args.length > 2 || args.length == 0){
        System.err.println("Usage: java Bank bankFile [batchFile]");
    }
    else{
        if(args.length == 2){ //batch mode
            processAccounts(args[0]);
            //BankBatch.processBatch(args);
            close(args[0]);
        }

        else if(args.length == 1){ // gui mode

        }
    }

}
```

Bank.processAccounts:

```
private static void processAccounts(String filepath){
    BufferedReader accountReader;
    File accountFile = new File(filepath);
    if(accountFile.isDirectory()){
        System.err.println("Usage: java Bank bankFile [batchFile]");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    if(accountFile.exists()){
        try{
            accountReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(accountFile));

            String line = accountReader.readLine();
            while(line != null && line != ""){//in case there are extra empty lines
                String[] s = line.split(" "); // parts of an account line: type, id, pin, balance
                if(s.length != 4) break; //incorrect format, shouldn't happen
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                System.out.println(line);
                int pin = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
                double balance = Double.parseDouble(s[3]);

                switch(s[0]){ //account type
                    case "x": 
                        System.out.println("case x");
                        accounts.add(new checkingAccount(id, pin, balance));
                        break;

                    case "c":
                        System.out.println("case c");
                        accounts.add(new cdAccount(id, pin, balance));
                        break;

                    case "s":
                        System.out.println("case s");
                        accounts.add(new savingsAccount(id, pin, balance));
                        break;
                }
                line = accountReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(accounts.get(0).toString());
            System.out.println(accounts.get(1).toString());
            System.out.println(accounts.get(2).toString());
            accountReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            //this shouldn't happen since we check to see if it exists
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Account.java:

```
public abstract class Account {
public Account(int id, int pin, double bal){
    Account.balance = bal;
    Account.pin = pin;
    Account.id = id;
}

public String toString(){
    return (acctType + " " + id + " " + pin + " " + balance);
}
```

Example of extending Account, all the accounts are similar:

```
public class checkingAccount extends Account {

public checkingAccount(int id, int pin, double bal){
    super(id, pin, bal);
    setAcctType('x');
    setMin(50);
}


/**
 * apply montly interest
 * checkings accounts have no interest, only penalties for having less than minimum
 */
@Override
public double applyInterest() { //only penalty with a checking account
    if (getBalance() > 5){
        withdraw(5);
        return -5;
    }
    else{
        double change =  Math.round((getBalance() * 0.10) * 100.0) / 100.0; //10% of balance, round to 2 decimal places
        withdraw(change);
        return -change;
    }
}
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
c 1111 1234 703.92
case c
x 2222 1234 100.00
case x
s 3333 1234 200.08
case s
s 3333 1234 200.08
s 3333 1234 200.08
s 3333 1234 200.08
========= Final Bank Data ==========

Acount Type   Account   Balance   
-----------   -------   -------
 Saving      3333    200.08
 Saving      3333    200.08
 Saving      3333    200.08

====================================
```

Comment: Show us the implementation of `toString` on `checkingAccount`.

Comment: Can you provide how you have declared the List of accounts type?

Comment: the `switch-case` is correct, you can put a debug `sout` statement in the each of the case and check. It is going into each of the case statement and executing it. I Guess you have defined the correct `toString()` for each of your custom class. Can you provide more code, This is looking correct.

Comment: `private static ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();` is how i created the list of accounts

Comment: `public String toString(){
  return (acctType + " " + id + " " + pin + " " + balance);` is the abstract account tostring method

Comment: I put a print statement in each case, and they are indeed going into the correct case.

Comment: Can you provide complete code of the main method of the method from which you have provide this code.

Comment: Updated the question with a lot more code.

Comment: I am getting the correct output. Are running the same code. This looks correct to me.

Comment: I'm still getting the repeated last account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Account.java, it looks like you may have made your variables in there static (but I'm not sure because their declarations are missing from your snippet).

Meaning, every time you construct an Account, those static variables are set to the new ones. Therefore, every time you access those variables in every object, they will be the same.

If all of these assumptions I've made are true, then all you have to do is remove the `static` keyword from your Account variable declarations and change your accessors from `Account.something` to `this.something`.

Comment: That did it! thank you so much, I would've never figured that out.